# How do I make my Discord bot check if a member is in a voice channel when running the join command?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am currently working on a music discord bot that I have been working on for a while now, but I couldn't seem to figure out how to get my bot to join the voice channel. So, I have completely erased everything, and I am starting from scratch. I have managed to code part of the bot, but I have run into an issue. That issue is that I don't quite seem to know how to make the music bot check to see if the author of the command is in a voice channel.

My code for my music bot.:

[image]

Comment: show code as text, not images. Please read [ask] and review the [tour]

Answer (score 1):

You are already checking if the member is in a voice channel *line 18*.
And to join a voice channel you can use the [VoiceChannel.join() method](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceChannel?scrollTo=join)

```js
if (msg.content.toLowerCase() === "+join") {
    if (msg.member.voice.channel) {
    msg.member.voice.channel.join();
    msg.channel.send("Successfully joined the voice channel");
  } else return message.channel.send("Please join a voice channel first");
}
```